# How to change type of information for a Title column in SharePoint MOSS 2007 List?

Tags: outlook, column

I created a calendar in SharePoint MOSS 2007 that is connected to my Outlook. I added a custom column “Person” to this list and the type of information in this column is:  Person or Group.  In SharePoint I can hide Title column and in Calendar View show this Person field as Month View Title. So I can see on the calendar who is working that day. Problem is in Outlook. It seems like Outlook doesn’t know a thing about custom fields. In Outlook I can see only Title and few other fields. I could rename Title field to Person, but I can’t change type of information that it contains. By default it is text field and no way to change it to Person or Group.

If I could change those “default” column types, then I think my problem would be solved. I know it is possible. I created a custom list, but this list has also those “sticky” Title, Created By and Modified By columns that can’t be changed or removed. Maybe I have to create a custom list with some other program or code?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an item receiver that populates the title field with the Display Name value in the Person column. It wouldn't be the full experience of the Person field, but at least it would contain something meaningful.

Comment: That would be a workaround, that would kin of do it, but I still hope, that there will be a solution to have that Title column with needed type of information

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a custom content type for the Calendar?  This will allow you to completely hide the Title fiend and it shouldn't be available for Outlook.  Once this is done, create a Calendar list, set it up to manage content types, remove the existing content type and replace it with your custom content type.  As far as the Created By and Modified By fields, though, I'm afraid I don't have a solution for that.

Comment: Custom content type sounds closer to what I need. But m maybe it should be a custom list? On post http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/1118/calculated-value-for-title-field
Anders mentioned that title field is mandatory only if we create lists using GUI. But I have no idea, about what code is he talking and how to use CAML.

Comment: That would work.  At the end of the day a Calendar is really just a list with a Calendar view.  You shouldn't need any CAML code if you just supply a custom content type.  The good news is you can always add it back if you decide you need it later on.

Comment: So I tried to create a custom content type thru SP user interface. There I need to choose a Parent Content Type which gives me this annoying Title column with unchangeable type of information: Single line of text. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Go ahead and create the content type.  For Calendars/Lists it should be based on the 'Item' type.  Once it's created, go down to the columns listed and delete the Title entry.

Comment: When I create a content type in this way, then there is one column called Title which has only editable parameters: Required or not and Update all content types inheriting from this site. No way to delete this column.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to convey the steps from memory and I goofed.  When you click on the Title column link, change the Column Settings field to Hidden.  This will effictively remove the Title column from your column type.

Comment: Hiding a column doesn't work for me. This field is needed to display information in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure changing the type of a title column is a good idea to be honest. Title is one of those built-in fields that SharePoint relies on being there as a string (think SPListItem.Title).

Changing the type of this column might work, but it also might break your calendar completely, especially when you try to connect Outlook to it. I'm guessing that Outlook would expect a Title string to come back from the web service when it gets data back.

I think MBSurf's idea would be the safest option.